# Filter in SQL query does not return in outcome

Tags: mysql, sql

Using the following code, I am trying to filter data on the date of the event (=.evSpeeldatum) and the discount type (=.tiPrijstype).

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
tickets
    JOIN
evenementen ON tickets.fk_tiEvenementID = evenementen.idEvenement
WHERE
evenementen.evSpeeldatum >= '2018-01-24'
    AND tickets.tiPrijstype = 2
    OR 3
    OR 4
    OR 5
    OR 6
    OR 66
    OR 67;
```

However, when I run this code both the outcome is not filtered on the date of the event nor the discount types (2 OR 3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 66 OR 67)

Comment: A fine example of random ands an ors.

Comment: @P.Salmon; I see now. The examples below provided the insights that I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `IN` like

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
tickets
    JOIN
evenementen ON tickets.fk_tiEvenementID = evenementen.idEvenement
WHERE
evenementen.evSpeeldatum >= '2018-01-24'
AND tickets.tiPrijstype IN(2,3,4,5,6,66,67);
```

Comment: Have to wait 5 min.. Will do asap!

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause is supposed to look at boolean expressions (comparisions mainly). These you can combine with `AND` and `OR`. For istance:

```
WHERE tickets.tiPrijstype = 2 OR tickets.tiPrijstype = 3
```

You however have `OR 3`. MySQL expects some boolean expression, so it surmises the 3 to represent a boolean value and converts the 3 silently to `true` (it converts 0 to `false` and all other values to `true`). So your

```
WHERE tickets.tiPrijstype = 2 OR 3
```

converts to

```
WHERE tickets.tiPrijstype = 2 OR true
```

which is true for every record.

Also be aware of operator precedence when mixing `AND` and `OR`. `AND` has precedence over `OR`. So

```
WHERE evenementen.evSpeeldatum >= '2018-01-24'
  AND tickets.tiPrijstype = 2
   OR tickets.tiPrijstype = 3
```

means

```
WHERE (evenementen.evSpeeldatum >= '2018-01-24' AND tickets.tiPrijstype = 2)
   OR tickets.tiPrijstype = 3
```

which again is not what you want. Use parentheses to get this straight:

```
WHERE evenementen.evSpeeldatum >= '2018-01-24'
  AND (tickets.tiPrijstype = 2 OR tickets.tiPrijstype = 3)
```

As has been shown, when checking for a value in a list, you'd use `IN` anyway, so the mentioned problem doesn't arise:

```
WHERE evenementen.evSpeeldatum >= '2018-01-24'
  AND tickets.tiPrijstype IN (2,3)
```

The whole query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tickets t
JOIN evenementen e ON t.fk_tiEvenementID = e.idEvenement
WHERE e.evSpeeldatum >= date '2018-01-24'
  AND t.tiPrijstype IN (2,3,4,5,6,66,67);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a valid query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tickets t
  JOIN evenementen e
    ON e.idEvenement = t.fk_tiEvenementID 
 WHERE e.evSpeeldatum >= '2018-01-24'
   AND (t.tiPrijstype = 2 OR t.tiPrijstype = 3);
```

...which can also be rewritten as...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tickets t
  JOIN evenementen e
    ON e.idEvenement = t.fk_tiEvenementID 
 WHERE e.evSpeeldatum >= '2018-01-24'
   AND t.tiPrijstype IN(2,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have records which will fall for this filter and if date is being saved in this format only, then following query will work,

```
 SELECT * FROM tickets JOIN evenementen ON tickets.fk_tiEvenementID = evenementen.idEvenement WHERE
 evenementen.evSpeeldatum >= '2018-01-24'
 AND tickets.tiPrijstype IN (2,3,4,5,6,66,67);
```